# iOS Custom View Text Labels Are Nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

Right now I have a custom view class called OTGMarkerDetailView which inherits from UIView and a corresponding .xib with it. It just has two text labels and I've linked the text labels to the text label IBOutlets in OTGMarkerDetailView.m.

OTGMarkerDetailsView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OTGMarkerDetailView : UIView

- (void)setLabelsWithMainAddress:(NSString *)mainAddress subAddress:(NSString *)subAddress;

@end
```

OTGMarkerDetailView.m

```
#import "OTGMarkerDetailView.h"

@interface OTGMarkerDetailView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *mainAddressLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *subAddressLabel;

@end

@implementation OTGMarkerDetailView

- (void)setLabelsWithMainAddress:(NSString *)mainAddress subAddress:(NSString *)subAddress {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.mainAddressLabel.text);
    self.mainAddressLabel.text = mainAddress;
    self.subAddressLabel.text = subAddress;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.mainAddressLabel.text);
}

@end
```

I load it in another view as a subview, using initWithFrame. But the console always logs null when I try to set the text label values, and when I use a breakpoint it seems the mainAddressLabel and the subAddressLabel are nil themselves. Did I do something wrong in linking the xib to the view? What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your custom view in another view using **initWithFrame** a new instance of your custom class is created. This instance is not the same one you have in interface builder and hence the label properties are nil for this newly created instance. In order to solve this problem either put your view in its parent view in interface builder with its connection attached or override **initWithFrame** for your custom view and initialise your labels in there.

Comment: So I would have to add this view in the interface builder for the view I'm trying to add it to?

Otherwise, I would have to manually instantiate each IBOutlet?

Comment: Yes that is one of the options. Otherwise just override initWithFrame for your custom view and initialise your labels there.

Comment: How can I utilize the labels I have put in my xib file? Is it possible not to create and place the labels programmatically?

Comment: In order to use interface builder to connect your labels. You will have to put your child view in your parent view in interface builder. So now your parent view will have your child view as it's sub view with its labels set when your nib file is loaded.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, nothing shows up in the parent view. I think I have to do something like loadWithNib, is this a possibility?

Answer (score 3):

I found a work around. I have created a custom UIView.

1.
I attached Nib file to it in **initWithFrame** method

```
CustomView *nibView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
        nibView = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:nibView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

You can see clearly, I haven't created the instance of UIView instead I created nibView of the same class type.

2.
Now creating IBOutlet properties and work on it. In customView.m file.

```
@interface FTEndorsedExpandedView : UIView

     @property (retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

3.
Create functions to set title or changing properties. (in customView.m file). Use **nibView** to access the properties rather than using **self.label**

```
-(void)setLabelText:(NSString*)string{
    [nibView.label setText:string];
}
```